# link_to delete, deleting wrong record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, iteration, haml, link-to

I'm having the strangest problem! In my RoR app, I have an .each loop. Each iteration has a link_to "Delete" for that specific iteration:

```
- @evints.each do |e|
    .inteventimg
      = link_to e.event.name, e.event
      = e.id
      %br
      - if e.event.images.exists?
        = image_tag(e.event.images.find_by(:prime => true).location.full.url)
      %br
      - if current_user 
        = link_to "Delete #{e.id}", e, :method => :delete, data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}
```

Evint is a join table in a has_many, through relationship between Interest and Event; in my Interests controller under show, I've defined @evints as @interest.evints.

Everything's working--the correct images are showing, the correct e.id is appearing both next to e.name and in the "Delete" link itself; yet consistently, the first evint on the page is deleted, rather than the one for which "Delete" is clicked. I can't figure it out . . . does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the delete code from the Evint Controller:

```
  def destroy
 @evint = Evint.find_by(params[:id])
 authorize @evint

if @evint.destroy
   flash[:notice] = "Your evint has been removed."
   redirect_to :back
else
  flash[:error] = "Evint couldn't be deleted. Please try again."
  redirect_to :back
end
```

end

Thank you.

Comment: Confirm that the correct controller#action is being called. And, can you post the delete action code?

Comment: I've added the controller action code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller code is incorrect:

```
@evint = Evint.find_by(params[:id])
```

should be either

```
@evint = Evint.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
@evint = Evint.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

As it is, the SQL generated will be of the form (assuming `params[:id]` was 123)

```
SELECT * from evints where (123) limit 1
```

Which will match any row in the database